# Is it possible to pass an "on the fly" array to a C function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, on-the-fly

In Fortran, one can pass an array constructed on the fly to a subroutine:

```
call sub_that_wants_3_elm_array((/1,2,3/),output_arg)
```

Is it possible to do something analogous in C?  This seems awfully basic, but I haven't been able to find anything on this, either yes or no.

Comment: Yes.It is called compound literals

Comment: Not studied well, Compound literals ([N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.5.2.5) might be it.

Comment: Why do beginners think all programming languages support the same (or similar) features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It's possible using *compound literals* (since C99).

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(int *a)
{
    printf("%d\n", a[2]); //prints 72
}

int main(void)
{
    fun((int[]){1, 99, 72});
}
```

You can find some more examples from the links as well:

1. [The New C: Compound Literals](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-compound-literals/184401404)
2. [Compound Literals - gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html)

Comment: Dang, it worked!  Want to give you an upvote but stackoverflow is making me wait.  Remind me if I don't get around to it.  Thanks!

Comment: @bob.sacamento did you mean to accept the answer ?

Comment: @machine_1 Oh ... yeah, that was it.  But it's all done now.